# OpenGL - Combine Vertex Array Object and Index Buffer (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER)

Tags: c++, opengl

I do want to use an Index Buffer (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY) together with an Vertex array object. I have the following code:

```
// Set stuff up
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayObjectId);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayObjectId);

glGenBuffers( 1, &ArrayBufferId );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ArrayBufferId );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * finalData.size() , finalGPUData, GL_STATIC_DRAW ); 

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 8, (GLvoid*) 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, sizeof(float) * 8, (GLvoid*) 12);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 8, (GLvoid*) 20);

glGenBuffers(1, &IndexBufferId);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBufferId);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, finalIndices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), finalGPUIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

//Render 
//Set up shader etc
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayObjectId);
//glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ArrayBufferId );
//glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 8, (GLvoid*) 0);
//glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, sizeof(float) * 8, (GLvoid*) 12);
//glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 8, (GLvoid*) 20);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, finalIndices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*) 0 );
```

According to my knowledge, the 4 lines of code, which are commented out are not necessary, because this information is stored in the VAO. (I mean, saving these calls is the purpose of the VAO) However if I run this code it only draws a few Triangles at the origin rather than at the correct vertex position. If I include these lines however, everything gets drawn correctly. So apparently the GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER information is stored correctly within the VAO, but the vertex attributes are not. Is my understanding wrong or are there simply mistakes in my code?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're using a core OpenGL profile, `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);` should have given you an error.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Why should this line give an error?

Comment: @BDL: Because [the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding is a part of the VAO's state](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers). And since he unbound the VAO, and core profile OpenGL doesn't have a default VAO, he would be modifying the state of an object that doesn't exist.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Yes, it is part of the VAO state and cannot be modified when no VAO is bound. But doing this does not produce an error. (At least not with the current NVIDIA driver, OpenGL 3.3 Core Profile).

Comment: @BDL: Huh. I just looked up the OpenGL specification, and sure enough, it does not state what the error should be for binding to that buffer target if no VAO is bound. That's... odd, since the function cannot have an effect if no VAO is bound.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks for the hint. However this seems to be independent of the actual problem. Removing this line does not change anything.

Comment: @NicolBolas You can bind an element array buffer while no VAO is bound in any OpenGL implementation I have tried it in. I was recently digging through the spec, and it's actually kind of odd. As you say, it's part of the VAO state, and the default VAO is deprecated. The clearest suggestion that there is indeed still a global element array buffer binding is this from the 4.5 spec: "Finally,the buffer bound to ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER may be queried by calling GetIntegerv with pname ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING."